# go вывод русских символов

Tags: golang

Всем привет.
Начинаю изучать язык Go и столкнулся с проблемой вывода русского текста.
Вот простой пример с ошибкой вывода:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Привет:")
}
```

Ошибка:

```
.\Println.go:8: illegal UTF-8 sequence
```

Подскажите из-за чего проблема и как ее решить ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает из-за того, что в файл `Println.go` сохранен не в Unicode, а в каком-нибудь CP1252.

Откройте файл в Notepad, и пересохраните его через `File`/`Save As` выбрав UTF-8 вместо ANSI. Или смените кодировку на UTF-8/Unicode with signature любым другим редактором.